# Minimax recurse back up the tree

Tags: algorithm, minimax

When I recurse back up, my board gets all messed up.

How can I return to the previous board without always copying (my minimax needs to be fast performance wise)

My code:

```
 for all possible moves:
            board.apply(move);
            int currentScore = minimax(board, depth - 1, false); // recursive call
            int newScore = Math.max(value, currentScore);
            // Undo move on the board or create a temp board for recursive calls, as the recursive calls will mess up the current board
            board.undo(move);
```

I thought of an undo method in the Board class that takes a move and undo it, but will that get me back to my current board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as long as you undo all the moves you apply in the opposite order, you'll get back the original board.  The `move` itself object would not normally carry enough information to undo itself, though, so an implementation would look more like:

```
for all possible moves:
    // apply the move and remember how to undo it
    undomove = board.apply(move);

    // minimax function promises to return the board unmodified
    int currentScore = minimax(board, depth - 1, false); // recursive call
    int newScore = Math.max(value, currentScore);

    // Undo move to recover the original board
    board.apply(undomove);
```

Comment: The move here is a string so it's kinda hard to go back to the previous state if the move I just applied killed a pawn, how could I undo the pawn that just got killed?

Comment: The value returned by `board.apply(move)` needs to indicate how to undo the move.  That means it has to indicate that the dead pawn should be replaced.  It doesn't really matter how you do that, but it must be done.  If you like, you can use a different method to apply undo moves, since there are more possibilities for them.  There is no reason the moves have to be stored as strings, though.

Comment: For example, a move (including an undo move) can be packed into a 17-bit int.  6 bits for source location, 6 bits for target location, 3 bits for piece to replace (normally at the source position), and 2 bits to indicate undoing an en passant capture on left or right

Comment: Thank you!!! Will this work: int[][] grid = board.apply(move); which grid is the board before the move and then instead of board.apply(undomove) I use board.setGrid(grid) What do you think?

Comment: The grid is 13 by 13, how expensive will it be? Thank you for the help btw, really appreciated

Comment: You'd really have to measure it, but doing it that way will probably make your algorithm take at least 5 times longer than it should, depending on how much everything else costs.